# "object does not have a __dict__, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the object class."

Tags: python, python-3.x

From https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#object

> `object` does not have a `__dict__`, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the `object` class.

Why "`object` does not have a `__dict__`"? 
It works for me

```
>>> object.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>, '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>, '__subclasshook__': <method '__subclasshook__' of 'object' objects>, '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>, '__format__': <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0xa3dc20>, '__doc__': 'The most base type', '__class__': <attribute '__class__' of 'object' objects>, '__dir__': <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>, '__delattr__': <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>, '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>, '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>, '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>, '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>, '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>, '__reduce__': <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>, '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>, '__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>, '__reduce_ex__': <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>, '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>, '__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>})
```

Why "you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the `object` class"?

Comment: Look at `object().__dict__`.

Comment: It is referring to instances of `object`, not the object type.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard the quote says "`object` does not have a `__dict__`" instead of "an instance of `object` does not have a `__dict__`". So how did I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are confusing the `__dict__` on the *type* with the attribute on instances. `object()` *instances* do not have a `__dict__` attribute:

```
 >>> object().__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Note that the `__dict__` attribute of custom Python class instances is a [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); the instance itself doesn't have the attribute, it is the class that provides it (so `type(instance).__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(instance)` is returned). `object.__dict__` may exist, but `object.__dict__['__dict__']` does not.

`object()` doesn't support instance attributes because it is the base for all custom Python classes, which must [support not having a `__dict__` attribute when defining slots instead](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: Thanks. If I am correct, an instance of a class has  `__dict__` attribute. So why doesn't an instance of  `object`   have `__dict__` attribute?

Comment: @Tim: because if it did, you couldn't have custom class instances *without* a `__dict__` attribute, such as for those classes that [have slots instead](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Comment: Thanks. Why "you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the object class"?

Comment: @Tim: You need a `__dict__` mapping to support arbitrary attributes. That's how arbitrary attributes *work*.

Comment: Does "an instance of object doesn't have `__dict__` attribute" imply that `object` class has `__slot__` attribute?

Comment: @Tim: no, it does not. `__slots__` defines fixed attributes *in addition* to what the base provided.

Comment: Thanks. "`object()` doesn't support instance attributes because it is the base for all custom Python classes". `object` is the base for all classes, while an instance of `object` is not. So why does an instance of `object` not have `__dict__` attribute?

Comment: @Tim: *Because* `object` is the base class for all custom classes, it informs instances. The class of the instance provides the `__dict__` descriptor; if `object` provided that then you can't have an instance without a `__dict__`. Ergo, `object()` instances can't have a `__dict__`.

Comment: "The class of the instance provides the `__dict__` descriptor; if `object` provided that then you can't have an instance without a `__dict__`". (1) Do you mean if a class has class attribute `__dict__` , then every instance of the class has instance attribute `__dict__`?  (2) here, the class `object` has class attribute `__dict__` , but  your reply says that the return of `object()`, i.e. any instance of the class `object`,  has no instance attribute `__dict__`. So isn't that contrary to (1)?

Comment: @Tim: I linked to the [descriptor howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for a reason. Please read it. Attributes on instances can be satisfied in 2 different ways: keys in the `__dict__`, and attributes on the class hierarchy. Attributes on the class hierarchy can be *descriptors*, which then get *bound* to the instance. `__dict__` is implemented as such a descriptor, so **the class supplies it**. So yes, because the class (or a parent of the class) has a `__dict__` attribute that happens to be a descriptor, that attribute works on all instances. Just like methods.

Comment: @Tim: Note that the same applies to `type`; it can supply descriptors for classes (including `object`). `object.__dict__` is not actually an attribute directly on `object`, it is a descriptor that `type` provides; `object.__dict__` is really `type.__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(object)`. There is no `object.__dict__['__dict__']` however.