# Why is `object()` not having `__dict__` to support the instances of some custom Python classes not having a `__dict__` attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880260

> `object()` doesn't support instance attributes because it is the base for all custom Python classes, which must [support not having a `__dict__` attribute when defining slots instead](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Does "it" in "it is the base for all custom Python classes" mean class `object` or its instance `object()`? I guess class `object`?

Since it is `object` instead of `object()` which is the base for all custom Python classes, is it also `object` instead of `object()` which must support the instances of some custom Python classes not having a `__dict__` attribute when the classes defining `__slots__` instead?

So how shall I understand that `object()` not having `__dict__` is to support the instances of some custom Python classes not having a `__dict__` attribute when the classes defining `__slots__` instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Per the ["Notes on using `__slots__`"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#notes-on-using-slots):

> When inheriting from a class without `__slots__`, the `__dict__` attribute of that class will always be accessible, so a `__slots__` definition in the subclass is meaningless.

The wording is a little imprecise; technically, since all classes inherit from `object` (which lacks `__slots__`), that would imply that instances would all have `__dict__`, but what they really mean to say is that if `__dict__` is not suppressed on instances at every level of the inheritance tree (by failing to provide `__dict__` for built-in types like `object`, or suppressing it with `__slots__` on user-defined classes), then a `__dict__` will exist for instances of the first class in the tree that fails to suppress `__dict__`, and for all of its subclasses, even if they try to use `__slots__` to suppress `__dict__`.

Basically, if `object` instances had `__dict__`, all instances of all classes would have it as well; by suppressing it on `object`, the subclasses of `object` (read: All classes) retain the *option* to have `__dict__` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Subclasses of `object` may not want a `__dict__` for their instances, but if `object` instances had one, their subclass instances will have one too.

The issue is mostly that `object` is the parent class of all other classes in Python. If it was designed so that its instances had a `__dict__`, that `__dict__` would be inherited by all instances of all classes.