# Why setting attributes of class object instances results in AttributeError?

Tags: python-3.x

Why the following code produces an error

```
>>> object().foo = 'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

while the next one works fine?

```
class A():
    pass

A().foo = 'bar'
```

What is the exact difference between A and object? I believe `o().foo = 'bar'` leads to `setattr('o', 'foo', 'bar')` and this in turn results in `o.__setattr__('foo', 'bar')`. One would expect them to have identic `__setattr__` methods since no overriding happens. Yet the outputs are different. Please explain why. What happens behind the scenes?

A similar pattern can be noticed for built-in functions and user-defined ones. I can't set my own attributes for let's say `dict` but it's perfectly ok to write `(lambda:None).foo = 'bar'`. What's going on here?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880260/3444923, object's instance does not have `__dict__`. The simplest check is just dir(...) what you want to check. dir(lamda: None) show that lambda type has `__dict__`